# VBA Referencing new mail merge document

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I'm currently working on an Excel Spreadsheet that creates a mail merge, then splits the mail merge into component files, without requiring any intervention once the program has started.

I'm having the issue that after the mail merge, the wdApplication focus moves back to the original word document, and I can't figure out how to either make the mail merge the active document, or to set a variable to be the new mail merge so I can manipulate it there.

Here's my current code:

```
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim strWorkbookName As String: strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
Dim sections As Integer
Dim fileName As String

With wdApp
    .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

    Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Potential Template.docx", ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False)

    With wdDoc
        With .MailMerge
            .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
            .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
            .SuppressBlankLines = True
            .OpenDataSource Name:=strWorkbookName, ReadOnly:=True, _
                LinkToSource:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
                Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
                Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=strWorkbookName;" & _
                "Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
                SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `'Final Data Set$'`", _
                SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
            With .DataSource
                .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
                .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
            End With
            .Execute
            .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
        End With
        .Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

    End With

    .Browser.Target = wdBrowseSection
    For i = 1 To ((ActiveDocument.sections.Count) - 1)
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Section").Range.Copy

        Documents.Add
        Selection.Paste

        Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        fileName = filePath & Worksheets("Final Data Set").Range(Cells(i + 1, 4)).value
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs (fileName)
        ActiveDocument.Close

        .Browser.Next
    Next i




    .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
    .Visible = True
    .Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the [MailMergeAfterMerge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/application-mailmergeaftermerge-event-word) Event of the Word Document.

However in order to be able to handle the event, you need to declare the Document as `Private WithEvents wdDoc As Word.Document` at module level.

```
Private Sub wdDoc_MailMergeAfterMerge(Doc As Document, DocResult As Document)
End Sub
```

> Occurs after all records in a mail merge have merged successfully.

```
Name       Data-Type  Description

Doc        Document   The mail merge main document.
DocResult  Document   The document created from the mail merge
```

Note `WithEvents` cannot be declared in a standard module.